# moment.js not creating right date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I cant seem to figure out what the issue is I have a manual time enter function on my website where a user can enter a time and then I store it in the db..

So my function looks like this..

```
createTime() {
    this.startTime =  moment(`${this.hour}:${this.minute} ${this.timeOfDay}`, `HH:mm a`).utc();
}
```

so I typed in 5:45pm

now when I `console.log()` the created moment I get this...

[image]

so its the right utc time but it says its in AUS TIME

then when I get the time back from the server and then try to convert it back to local time like so..

```
fixTime(momentObject: moment.Moment) {
    return moment(momentObject).local().format('hh:mm A');
}
```

I get 4:45am

I can not figure out what the issue is.. how can I fix this?

Comment: When you write `5:45 pm` do you mean that in AEDT or UTC?

Comment: So when the user enters the time its in localtime so AEDT then I convert it to utc using the `createTime` function

Comment: And how are you sending the moment to the server and getting it back?

Comment: So I'm sending it as the moment, the server stores the moment and sends it back exactly the same

Comment: You can't send JavaScript objects across HTTP. So are you encoding it as JSON, as a string, as a numeric Unix timestamp, or...?

Comment: Sorry I'm not entirely sure.. must be a string

Comment: This http://jsfiddle.net/v5wdq6o7/ works as expected for me. You'll have to show us exactly what is sent to the server and then what is received from the server.

Answer (score 0):

```
   fixTime(momentObject: moment.Moment) {

    var testDateUtc = moment.utc(momentObject);
    var localDate = moment(testDateUtc).local();
    return localDate.format('hh:mm A');
}
```

you must  Create a moment object and set the UTC flag to true on the object and Create a localized moment object converted from the original moment object and finally Return a formatted string from the localized moment 
    object.

See: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/local/